# How do you get the boxes in sanctuary?

Tags: borderlands-2

There's one in the cage in your house, and another by the Fast Travel Station. How do you get to these boxes?

I just want to get the stuff inside so I'm have a better arsenal and stop dying as much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later on, on the main story line, the cage doors will be opened for you by an NPC. There is no way (short of hacking) that will permit you sooner.

> The cage will be opened when Roland is captured by the enemy, in a cutscene.

Comment: Thank you that is awesome it helps a lot do you lnow what mission